# React, html strings and components

Tags: reactjs

Say we have an HTML string. It looks like this:

```
"<p>Australia is the capital of Canada<footnote>No, it isn't</footnote></p>
 <p>Australia's most famous animal<footnote>There are no animals in 
 Australia</footnote> is the panda</p>"
```

Now say we wanted to build a react component that could convert that string to HTML, pull all of the footnote elements out of the `<p>` tags and then replace them with a marker that shows there is a footnote. Like so:

```
<p>Australia is the capital of Canada<a href="footnote-1">[1]</a></p>
<p>Australia's most famous animal<a href="footnote-2">[2]</a>is the panda</p>

...
<span id="footnote-1">No, it isn't</span>
<span id="footnote-2">There are no animals in Australia</span>
```

What would be the "react way" of pulling those footnotes out and replacing them? *Is* there a "react way" of doing manipulations of this sort? My current implementation is this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false;
}
// a whole lot of vanilla javascript
```

It's not ideal.

I realize the answer to this question might be rather lengthy, so I'd be happy with just some general hints.

Comment: Your current implementation is... nothing? Sorry, you're going to have to at least show what you've attempted so far, otherwise this is going to be closed as Too Broad.

Comment: As for the question at hand, React is geared towards rendering HTML components, not transforming existing HTML. The latter requires DOM manipulation which React explicitly attempts to avoid - IMO you're better off with a standard Javascript/jQuery solution to this problem.

Comment: You might want to look into something like this: [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Comment: @Ian Kemp My current implementation is vanilla javascript cordoned off with shouldComponentUpdate() {return false;} I have no better solution right now. Maybe there is no better solution.